# Webpack Node API provides noisier output then CLI

Tags: node.js, webpack, output, command-line-interface

## Problem

Webpack provides the ability to run the builds, including watch mode, via either CLI or Node API.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to mimic the output CLI prints to the stdout, using API.

When using CLI in watch mode, only the changed chunk is printed and marked as `[emitted]`, and all the rest are skipped entirely.

When using API in watch mode, all the chunks are printed, and the changed one is marked as `[emitted]`

*The problem* is when there is a large amount of these chunks, the API output becomes extremely noisy (there can be as many as 50 *total* chunks and other non-webpack related print-outs), which is something *I would like to avoid*.

The API output is configured in the following manner:

```
compiler.watch({}, (err, stats) => {
    if (!err) {
        const out = stats.toString({
            assets: true,
            cached: false,
            children: false,
            chunks: false,
            chunkModules: false,
            colors: true,
            hash: true,
            modules: false,
            reasons: false,
            source: false,
            timings: true,
            version: true
        });
        console.log(out);
    } else {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

## Question

Can someone suggest a combination of `stats.toString` configuration properties above to produce the same "small" output using Node API?

## Illustration

#### Setup

There are 2 files: `author.js` and `article.js`.

Both API and CLI modes use the same physical `webpack.config.js` file and produce *identical* bundles.

#### When run in watch mode using CLI

**Action**: change-and-save in `author.js` file

**Output**:

[image]

#### When run using `compiler.watch` via Node API

**Action**: change-and-save in `author.js` file

**Output**:

[image]